# Possible error in Contributions and Membership Details report

Tags: civicontribute, civireport

When we run the Contributions and Membership details report for our organization, it reports 41 entries in the month:

Row(s) Listed   41
Total Amount    $ 1,320.00(44)
Average     $ 30.00

However, when the 41 rows are exported as a CSV, the amounts total to $45 less.

What is the meaning of the "(44)" beside the total amount?  I suspect it represents that the total is based on 44 rows instead of 41 which would account for why the total is erroneously high.

Is this a "feature" or a "bug"?   If a feature, how can I figure out the three extra rows since they do not show up anywhere in the report

Incidentally, if I do the same as a "Find contributions" search, it returns 41 rows and the correct total dollar amount for those 41.

---

This is version 4.5.8, and the organization has not been using soft credits in its operations.

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify the version of CiviCRM you're using? Depending on CiviCRM version, you might be seeing one of these issues -

- [CRM-16636 Duplicate primary addresses causes error in report](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16636) (issue opened as a result of this response, see comments)
- [CRM-16338 Incorrect Contribution Summary Report when a contributions has multiple soft credits](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16338) (<= 4.6.3)
- [CRM-15374 Contribution FEES are affecting Balance and Total Paid incorrectly](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15374) (<= 4.5.1)
- [CRM-11703 Contribution and Membership Details report showing incorrect contribution amounts](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-11703) (<= 4.2.8)

You could search https://issues.civicrm.org/ for other issues if none of those seems like your case (you'll know if you're using soft credits, contribution fees etc).

If you are seeing the issue on a version of CiviCRM that is marked fixed above, post a message on that issue URL - you may be able to assist by providing some (anonymised) example DB data for the core team.

Comment: This is now resolved.   For some unknown reason a few contact records ended up with two primary addresses (is_primary = 1).  Once this was fixed, the report error disappeared.

At this point, I have no idea how the underlying civicrm_address table problem occurred.   We think it may be associated with merging duplicate contacts but I have not been able to duplicate the situation when I test it.

Comment: Good work tracking it down! Suggest reporting that as an issue against the report - at least that will document it for others, and it might even get fixed :) https://issues.civicrm.org

Comment: I've now posted it in the bug tracker.   I was hoping to uncover how the duplicate primary addresses were created.   Our principal user thinks it may have been caused by merging duplicate contacts, but I've not been able to replicate the situation.

I was hoping for more information before submitting it to issues.

Comment: That's fine. I think "report does wrong thing when duplicate primary addresses" and "doing X can cause multiple primary addresses" are different bugs, which combined for you (but the report total bug might also affect others who got into the same situation via a different route). Having them in the issue queue helps put them on the radar, and linking between the two means you can continue discussion here if need be.